# PostgreSQL - Find corresponding table of a LOB

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

When a table A uses a LOB, PostgreSQL stores it in a separate table, `pg_largeobject`, and table A holds a reference to an entry in `pg_largeobject`.

Given a LOB entry in `pg_largeobject` (or more specifically, the LOB ID), is there a way to find out the table that owns said LOB?

Answer (score 0):

No. It doesn't even need to be referenced by any table at all.  A LOB could be completely unreferenced, or could be referenced only by an OID which someone jotted down on a sticky note and then put in a safe deposit box.

You could make the same pragmatic assumption that vacuumlo does, and scour every table with columns of type "oid" or "lo".